# select the row with number most close to certain value

Tags: excel

I have a set of data with 3 column (example shown in the figure). The second column (height) is starting from 1 and increased to ~80 and then starting from 1 again. I need to select the row with the second column most close to 50. As shown in the figure below, I will need to select 3 rows. Can any one suggest how to find out those rows in excel?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=match(50, B1:B80, 1)
```

will find the element that has the largest value less than or equal to 50 in that range (choose your ranges accordingly). I believe B1:B80 must be in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear. It's not in ascending order. In my example, the second column (height) is starting from 1 and increased to ~80 and then starting from 1 again (row 1--8, 9--16 and 17--26). So my objective is to select the 3 rows (underlined) actually.

Comment: In your example, height does at least appear to be in ascending order. If your columns are `A, B and C`, then in `D8` you could use `=match(50, B1:B8, 1)` and in `D16` you could have `=match(50, B9:B16, 1)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! This will work. But the problem is that I have thousands rows of data. I have to input the range manually with this method. I am wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: Probably not without vba.